# Using selenium, how to detect internet explorer browser plugin?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was just trying to understand, is it possible to detect the internet explorer browser plugins using selenium? For Eg. I am trying to open a URL on IE browser and then I want to check if the browser has any plugins or not. how to do I automate this using selenium?

Answer (score 3):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/02/05/run-your-coded-ui-tests-against-chrome-using-the-selenium-toolkit.aspx

This will sort out your issue..(hope so)!

Comment: I want to do only on IE browser

Comment: You can not install selenium IDE in IE.
But you can run selenium IDE test case in IE or google chrome from command prompt.
For that you need to download selenium server standalone file.
http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/07/steps-of-running-selenium-ide-test.html[^] will show you all steps to running selenium IDE test case in IE or google chrome. @user2511126